# NSData contentsOfUrl returning nil when image is big

Tags: swift, nsdata

I am getting an image url from facebook. When image is big its return me nil image but image is shown in browser.

I have seen the same question on StackOverflow but it's not working, data1 returns null please check this code:

```
self.delegate.getFacebook_TimeLIne_image = "https://fbcdn-sphotos-c-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xfp1/v/t1.0-9/s720x720/12004969_1700631703502015_9114538119221669760_n.jpg?oh=a8ebcac0b2c4152a34855d1c82be3ffe&oe=5696E6BF&__gda__=1449299822_646985c21bc069691493b674069f88ab"
var getUrl_back:String = self.delegate.getFacebook_TimeLIne_image
if(!getUrl_back.isEmpty)
{
    if let url = NSURL(string: getUrl_back) {       
        let data1 = NSData(contentsOfURL: url)
        println(data1)
    }
}
```

Is any other option for show image , Because this image is working in Android so why in ios Please Give me solution

Comment: use asynchronous call

Answer (score 0):

As @karthikeyan said, you should be using an asynchronous call. In case you don't the main thread will be block until the Facebook image is downloaded.

You should have something like about asynchronous calls:

```
   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        ...
   }
```

Take a look at GCD Documentation for more info https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/

If it only returns nil when you are accessing to a big file, it seems that your device is not able to allocate memory enough to handle it.

Try to get the specific error returned:

```
   var error: NSError?
   let data1 = NSData(contentsOfURL:url , options: nil, error: &error)
   if let err = error{
       println(err)
   } else {
       println(data1)
   }
```

Also you shouldn't use NSData(contentsOfURL) for retrieving a big file, use instead a NSInputStream as told in the documentation:

> This method is ideal for converting data:// URLs to NSData objects, and can also be used for reading short files synchronously. If you need to read potentially large files, use inputStreamWithURL: to open a stream, then read the file a piece at a time.